# Low Level KeyBoardStruct

Tags: c#, keyboard

What is purpose of lparam.flags in KeyBoardStruct ? 
what is meaning of following statements

```
lparam.flags=0
lparam.flags=1
lparam.flags=32
```

???????

Answer (score 1):

When the [`LowLevelKeyboardProc` callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985.aspx) is called, the `lParam` parameter is a pointer to a [`KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644967.aspx).

And the documentation tells us the following about the `flags` member of that structure:

[image]

Comment: i have already seen this but will you clear what is meaning of 0,1,32 for the flags

Comment: @Xeshan: Uh, you test the value of the `flags` member by AND-ing it with the specified constants. So `if (lParam.flags & LLKHF_ALTDOWN))` will tell you whether the ALT key is pressed down. I don't know where you're getting those values, but you aren't supposed to set the values yourself.

Comment: wel bro check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Keystroke_Message_Flags

Comment: @Xeshan: That's telling you the memory layout of the structure. It's the exact same thing as displayed in the bottom chart in the documentation I linked to above. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @CodyThis code is used to detect Alt+Tab, Alt+Esc, Ctrl+Esc, Windows Key                                                                if (((lParam.vkCode == 9) && (lParam.flags == 32)) ||
                    ((lParam.vkCode == 27) && (lParam.flags == 32)) || ((lParam.vkCode ==
                    27) && (lParam.flags == 0)) || ((lParam.vkCode == 91) && (lParam.flags
                    == 1)) || ((lParam.vkCode == 92) && (lParam.flags == 1)) || ((true) &&
                    (lParam.flags == 32)))

Comment: @Xeshan: Right. Pay attention to the `vkCode` being tested. That stands for virtual key code. Each key has its own unique identifier. Why wasn't all of this information included in your question?

Comment: this is working fine but i want to know meaning of lparam.flag ??

Comment: M sorry for not elaborating my question in a good way ;-( i just want to get details about flags, as you have already seen that this flag is 32bits and 32 means 6th bit is on so what does it mean here ??

Comment: That code is meaningless. The only significant thing you're actually checking for is the virtual key code. The `flags` member is a *bit field*, and you're checking for equality. And at least one of those equality tests is against `true`. That's just noise.

Comment: @Codylparam.flags 0  = Ctrl Key
lparam.flags 1  = Left Windows Key
lparam.flags 32 = Alt Key. How you come to know 0 means Alt Key and 32 means Ctrl Key

Comment: **Where are you getting all of this information from?** You *don't* know that. The point is to test the bit flags using the constants shown. I'm sorry, I still don't get what is being asked. The question keeps changing before I can answer it.

Comment: this code means some thing because i want to block some combination keys and when i remove lparam.flags from if condition Alt+F4 close the window and when i use them in code i can also block Alt+F4 combination